# Calling PHP Webservice from C# using supplied WSDL

Tags: c#, php, web-services, wsdl

I've been passed a WSDL from a third party. Their web service is PHP on Apache.

I can call its methods from within XMLSpy and Validwsdl.com. But cannot get my C#/Visual Studio project to build/validate the WSDL. When I add it to my project - it shows all of the methods and seems fine but won't build.

I've tried add web ref, add service ref, I've tried command line WSDL.exe. Nothing works. Should I be having to hack at their WSDL document? Do I need extra libraries/includes?

I don't understand why it's not working.

The WSDL is :-

http://www.gesundsolutions.com/epp/application/heiq.wsdl

Any Ideas?

Comment: If it doesn't build, you receive an error. What's that error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the "Add Web Reference" from the menu in VS?

A simple and quick tutorial that shows you what is needed for communicating with a web service from elsewhere is [this post on op0.com](http://blog.op0.com/calling-a-web-service-with-c). Check it to find out what you're possibly missing.

Yes, just the WSDL is enough if you know the location of the web service. No, you should never change the WSDL, as that is the calling convention.